# How to call a dll function?

Tags: autohotkey

Consider a custom DLL named `MyDll.dll` that includes a function `MyFunction`.

This function is declared in C++ as follows:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MyFunction(int a, int b);
```

I'm looking to invoke this function from an AutoHotkey script.
However, i'm uncertain about the correct usage of `DllCall` to call this function.